# Converting gulp 3.0 task to gulp 4.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, gulp

I have a gulp script that was initially written for gulp 3.0. But after the update following task is failing due to a newer design. The following article describes this problem,

[gulp 4.0](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/)

```
    gulp.task("tsbuild", ["lint", "lint-css", "tsbuild-vendor"], () => {
    runWebpack(configFile);
});
```

Above code is throwing following error,

> throw new assert.AssertionError({
>     ^
>   AssertionError: Task function must be specified

I am building a complex web application and want to get rid of the error. Learning gulp is way out of my scope as I just need to build the web application. Can someone point me to the correct conversion of the above code snippet following Gulp 4.0 guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few different ways to do this, but here's my take:

When I converted from Gulp 3 to 4, I started using a different syntax than `gulp.task()'. If you're trying to run tasks in your build command in a series, you can import:

```
const { series } = require('gulp');
```

And then create a build task using the syntax:

```js
exports.tsbuild = series(lint, lint-css, tsbuild-vendor);
```

Or, if you're trying to run all your tasks in parallel, swap `series` for `parallel`:

```js
const { parallel } = require('gulp');

exports.tsbuild = parallel(lint, lint-css, tsbuild-vendor);
```

Additionally, you can change the syntax of your individual tasks to a function format like so:

```js
function lint() {
  // task operations go in here
}
```

I hope that makes sense. If you'd like more context, my full Gulp setup using version 4 can be found [here](https://github.com/DanBuda11/gulp-framework).